fastq files name containing "tmp"
My fastq files been downloaded from the sequencer, however some of the files downloaded in different format/name. my usual format is fastq.gz, although I have got fastq.tmp.gz for some of them. Does someone know what is tmp?
I have not tried to rename the file; should I?
